# SQL statement to filter by last 5 years

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a SQL statement that filters the last 5 years of data I've added the below where clause which would take me to exactly 5 years from today.

I wanted to ask how I would improve this statement to contain all data in the 5th year as well.

e.g. The data would not be from the date 16/11/2016 but from 01/01/2016 if it was run today.

Where statement:

```sql
WHERE CreatedDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-5,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DATEFROMPARTS` is your friend:

```sql
WHERE CreatedDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-5,1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 5, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably have a `year` function you can directly use :

```sql
where year(CreatedDate) >= year(GETDATE()) - 5
```

Comment: Note that this will not be SARGable, so any indexes on the column `CreatedDate` won't be able to be used.